# Laravel more dimesions array validation

Tags: laravel

There is a request.How I can validate it? I trying with foreach, but i does not work. Thanks.

The request:

```
'show_data' => [
                    0 => [
                        'buyer_search_property_id' => 1,
                        'date_of_show' => '2019-01-01',
                        'comment' => 'Nice flat',
                    ],
                    1 => [
                        'buyer_search_property_id' => 2,
                        'date_of_show' => '2019-01-31',
                        'comment' => 'Too small',
                    ], etc... 

                ],
```

I tried this, but it does not work (of course... :))

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [];

        foreach ($this['show_data'] as $key => $item) {
            $rules["show_data[$key]['buyer_search_property_id']"] = 'required';
            $rules["show_data[$key]['date_of_show']"] = 'required|date';
            $rules["show_data[$key]['comment']"] = 'required';
        }

        return $rules;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from laravel documentation:

You may also validate each element of an array. For example, to validate that each e-mail in a given array input field is unique, you may do the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
    'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
]);
```

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validating-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate array in laravel easily like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "show_data.*.buyer_search_propery_id" => "required",
        "show_data.*.date_of_show" => "required|date",
        "show_data.*.comment" => "required",
    ];
}
```

if you want your method to work, do this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [];

    foreach ($this['show_data'] as $key => $item) {
        $rules["show_data.$key.buyer_search_property_id"] = 'required';
        $rules["show_data.key.date_of_show"] = 'required|date';
        $rules["show_data.$key.comment"] = 'required';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

just remove the inner square brackets and the quotes and add dots to the indices, so change `$rules["show_data[$key]['date_of_show']"]` to `$rules["show_data.$key.date_of_show"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $data['show_data'] = [
            0 => [
                    'buyer_search_property_id' => 1,
                    'date_of_show'             => '2019-01-01',
                    'comment'                  => 'Nice flat',
            ],
            1 => [
                    'buyer_search_property_id' => 2,
                    'date_of_show'             => '2019-01-31',
                    'comment'                  => 'Too small',
            ],

    ];

    $rules = [
            'show_data.*.buyer_search_property_id' => 'required',
            'show_data.*.date_of_show'             => 'required|date',
            'show_data.*.comment'                  => 'required',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

Note asteriks at rules. With this you don't need a foreach loop. And it looks and feels a lot cleaner.